# Fast Fourier Transform: using templated derived classes 'undefined reference' error even though header and .cpp file match

Tags: c++, vector, fft, allocator, complextype

I'm coding a Fast Fourier Transform algorithm that does the Cooley Tukey method recursively using complex vectors.  The header file and the .cpp file match in parameter name and syntax, but I get the 'undefined reference' error still.  Due to the "extra" allocator parameter being mentioned in the error.  I think this might have something to do with using a template for our abstract base class and derived Cooley-tukey class.  All of the problems have come from the FFF_REC function that recursively divides up the input.

Github: https://github.com/ProgrammerB/Fourier-Transform-Terminal-/blob/master/classes/cooley-tukey.h

I've already tried to change my parameters to references and add a private member into the cooley-tukey class, but I get the same error.

Cooley-Tukey Class:

```
template<typename T>
class Cooley_tukey: protected Fourier<T>{
public:
    Cooley_tukey();
    Cooley_tukey(std::string file_name, double frequency, double, 
      frequency_step, std::string output_name);
    //~Cooley_tukey();

    void FFT(const std::vector<T> &index, const std::vector<T> &value);

    std::vector<complex<T>> FFT_REC(std::vector<complex<T>> &temp, int 
      total_time); //recursion function for FFT

private:
    int total_time;
```

};

Part of the error:

```
classes\cooley-tukey.cpp:91:10: error: no matching function for call to 
'Cooley_tukey<double>::FFT_REC(std::vector<std::complex<double>, 
std::allocator<std::complex<double> > > [(total_time / 2)], int, 
std::vector<std::complex<double>, std::allocator<std::complex<double> > 
>&)'FFT_REC(odd, total_time/2, result);
```

FFT-Recursion function(source of errors):

```
    template<typename T>
    std::vector<complex<T>> Cooley_tukey<T>::FFT_REC(std::vector<complex<T>>& temp, int total_time)
    {
        // Check if it is split up enough
        if (total_time >= 2)
        {

            // Split even and odds up
            std::vector<complex<T>> odd[total_time/2];
            std::vector<complex<T>> even[total_time/2];
            for (int i = 0; i < total_time / 2; i++)
            {
                even->at(i) = temp.at(i*2);
                odd->at(i)  = temp.at(i*2+1);
            }

            // Split up tasks through FFT recursion method
            FFT_REC(even, total_time/2);
            FFT_REC(odd, total_time/2);


            // DFT portion of FFT - calculates after everything has been split up through FFT_REC
            for (int frequency = 0; frequency < total_time / 2; frequency += this->frequency_step)
            {
                std::complex<T> t = exp(std::complex<T>(0, -2 * M_PI * frequency / total_time)) * odd->at(frequency);

                //Result of Cooley-Tukey algorithm:
                    //*This gives us the frequency values at certain times
                temp.at(frequency) = even->at(frequency) + t;
                temp.at(total_time / 2 + frequency) = even->at(frequency) - t;

            }
        }
        return temp;
    }

    template class Cooley_tukey<double>;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 0):

You’re creating an array of vectors as `even`/`odd` whereas you should just have a vector. The error says there isn’t a method that takes an array of vectors.

I assume you mean:

```
// Split even and odds up
std::vector<complex<T>> odd;
std::vector<complex<T>> even;
odd.reserve(total_time/2);
even.reserve(total_time/2);
for (int i = 0; i < total_time / 2; i++)
{
    even.push_back(temp.at(i*2));
    odd.push_back(temp.at(i*2+1));
}
```

You were also trying to use the `at()` to set values into empty vectors which would’ve caused errors. Vectors may not have any storage allocated and if you try to index them with `at()` you’ll get an exception when it goes out of bounds.